# How to estimate the maximum number of reads and writes per second a RDBMS server can handle?

Tags: sql, database

Before spinning up an actual (MySQL, Postgres, etc) database, are there ways to estimate how many reads & writes per second the database can handle?

I'm assuming this is dependant on the CPU and memory (+ network if we're sharding), but is there a good best practice on how to put these variables together?

This is useful for estimating cost and understanding how much of a traffic spike can the db handle.

Comment: Read the documentation for the database you are using.  Run tests.

Answer (score 8):

You can learn from others to gauge transactions per second you'll get from certain instances. For example, https://aiven.io/blog/postgresql-12-gcp-aws-performance gives you a good idea of how PostgreSQL 12 performs.

Percona has blogged about performance benchmarks also: https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/01/06/millions-queries-per-second-postgresql-and-mysql-peaceful-battle-at-modern-demanding-workloads/

Here's another benchmark with useful information: http://dimitrik.free.fr/blog/posts/mysql-performance-80-and-sysbench-oltp_rw-updatenokey.html about MySQL 8.0 and links to 5.7 performance.

There are several blogs about SQL Server performance such as https://storagehub.vmware.com/t/microsoft-sql-server-2017-database-on-vmware-vsan-tm-6-7-using-vmware-cloud-foundation-tm/performance-test-results/ that can also help you recognize the workloads these databases can handle.

Under 10K tps shouldn't be much of a problem with modern hardware. You can start with a most common configuration on the cloud or a standard sized server in your own environment. Use SSDs. Optimize your server settings to gain more speed and be ready to add more resources gradually. As Gordon mentions, benchmark your database after you have installed it. I'd start with 32G memory, 8 cores and SSDs to pull 10K tps as a thumbrule and adjust from there.

As you assumed, a lot depends on the # and type of CPU/memory/SSD, your workload, how you structure data, latency between your app and database, reporting happening against the database, master/slave configuration, types of transactions, storage engines etc.